# c# filter xml file by attribute and show in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter

I have looked and can't find the answer, I'm sure I'm just not looking for the right keywords, lol.

I have an XML file that I display in a datagridview, this all works fine. I'm trying to implant where I can click a button and 'reload' the datagridview with only certain parts of the xml file.

I will describe better. Just bear with me, I'm not the best at explaining.

This is the layout of my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Movies>
  <Name Name="Saw" Type="Horror" Year="2004-10-29" Overview="Overview">Saw</Name>
  <Name Name="Saw II" Type="Horror" Year="2005-10-28" Overview="Overview">Saw II</Name>
  <Name Name="Speed" Type="Action" Year="1994-06-10" Overview="Overview">Speed</Name>
  <Name Name="Batman Begins" Type="Action" Year="2005-06-17" Overview="Overview">Batman Begins</Name>
</Movies>
```

When I display normally I have it in a grid view like so.
I had to upload image elsewhere the site wouldn't let me put it here.
[enter link description here](http://screensnapr.com/e/ziyVvn.png)

Now what I'm trying to do is make is where when I click a button I can display only certain Movie Types. Say for example, click a button and only display movies that are "Action".

I have found information on this and got where I can select only the actions. I got them to pop up in messageboxs'

```
                XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load("movie.xml");

            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Movies/Name[@Type='Action']");
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(xn.InnerText);
            }
```

This actually shows say from the image the 2 movies that are action. But I can't figure out how to reload the datagridview with only these entries, and prefer with all information as before.

If I didn't explain clearly please say so, as I said before I know I"m not the best at explaining things.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to load the xml into a DataTable. Then you can use its in-memory filtering capability to filter the grid.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("Movies.xml");
this.dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Then you can filter it like this

```
private void FilterByType(string type)
{
            var dataView = ((DataTable) this.dataGridView.DataSource).DefaultView;
            dataView.RowFilter = "(Type = '" + type + "')";
}
```

To filter by substring use this syntax

```
dataView.RowFilter = "(Type LIKE *'" + substring + "*')";
```

Comment: I have tried your method here. I still come to errors, I'm sure it is me just being a noob. 

I tried loading like you showed, but the grid returns a blank.

            DataSet movies = new DataSet("Name");
            string filePath = "movie.xml";
            movies.ReadXml(filePath);
            
            dataGridView1.DataSource = movies.Tables[0];
            FilterByType("Action");

Comment: Have you defined the columns for the datagridview? If not try to set dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true before you set DataSource.

Comment: Now I have tried

DataSet movies = new DataSet();
string filePath = "movie.xml";
movies.ReadXml(filePath);

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
DataGridView1.DataSource = moives.Tables[0];
FilterByType("Action");


Same result, it returns an empty datagridview. Do you think it might be because on load of program, the datagridview show all moives in the list. For big list this is reason on trying to get this so I can cut list to only certain gendre

Again, thank you for taking time out and helping me. It is greatly appreciated.