# filter an xml file while loading datatable

Tags: c#, .net, xml, filter, dataset

```
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            ds.ReadXml("File.xml");
            dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
            LoadListView(dataTable);  

  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Book>
       <note1>
        <to>Tove</to>
        <from>Jani</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
      </note1>
    </Book>
```

I am reading whole xml file in dataset and then dispaly all records to Listview.
But when i load all data to listview Memory consumption is more. Datatable takes all memory of my machine and off course at some time gives me an exception out of memory Exception.Is it possible to load datatable after filter.
Above is my xml file having multiple nodes **i have to load only those nodes in datatable having XmlElement from starts with 'j'.**
I will appreciate for the answers.
**I dont want to use XMlDocument or Xpathquery or LINQ to XML**

Comment: Why would you not want to use any of the tools / functionality that's available to you.. ? just curious Linq to XML is pretty powerful

Comment: The .Net Framework gives you several tools to get the job done correctly.  Not using all of them really ties your hands and, frankly, causes you do to things in less efficient ways.  When you do things in less efficient ways, you get out of memory exceptions...

Comment: look at using this `DataTable.Select` you can write an Expression to Filter `2003 OUCH can you say UPGRADE`.. wow I haven't touched 2003 in EONS

Comment: Dj but datable is load first and then we use filter expression..I want to filter xml file while loading datatable

Comment: Take a look at this link sounds like similar thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602313/c-sharp-filter-xml-file-by-attribute-and-show-in-datagridview

Comment: DJ above ans tol me in-memory filtering capability..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on the quite weak assumption that you know the XML file's structure (i.e. the format is has a stable, uniform structure). Also I don't know what performance improvement this would bring in your case (as more objects are instantiated). But let's give it a try.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        List<int> positions = new List<int>();
        bool checkNext = false;
        int position = -1;

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("to");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("from");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("heading");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("body");

        var rs = new XmlReaderSettings();
        rs.IgnoreWhitespace = true;

        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(File.OpenRead("data.xml"), rs))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.Name == "")
                {
                    list.Add(reader.Value);
                    position++;
                }
                if (checkNext)
                {
                    // TODO: apply your filter
                    if (reader.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("j"))
                    {
                        positions.Add(position);
                    }
                }
                if (reader.Name == "from")
                {
                    checkNext = !checkNext;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (int match in positions)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(
                list[match - 1],
                list[match],
                list[match + 1],
                list[match + 2]);
        }

        //LoadListView(dataTable);  
    }
}
```